# d3.js: Is there a way to get a linear color-output for an array of elements?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a way to get a linear color-output for and array of elements?

Right now I'm using the following, which isn't pretty and the risk is also that I might have more elements in my array than I have colors here so then I'll just have to add more colors here.

I'm right now filtering out a number of elements and the "theExports" array does basically look like ["element1", "element2", "element3", ...] and is an array of strings.

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain([theExports])
        .range(["#e69a61", "#9817ff", "#18c61a", "#33b4ff", "#c9167e", "#297853", "#d7011b", "#7456c7", "#7e6276", "#afb113", "#fd879c", "#fb78fa", "#24c373", "#45bbc5", "#766b21", "#abad93", "#c19ce3", "#fd8f11", "#2f56ff", "#307a11", "#b3483c", "#0d7396", "#94b665", "#9d4d91", "#b807c8", "#086cbf", "#a2abc5", "#a35702", "#d3084b", "#8c6148", "#fa82ce", "#71be42", "#2bc0a0", "#b64064", "#d09fa2"]);
```

Either way it isn't really pretty or very functional, especially if I'd like to adjust the colors.
Right now I think it would be ideal if I managed to either plot it vs a linear color scale, or even better stepping it between say 3 or four colors like ["yellow", "red", "green", "blue"].

Using linear instead of ordinal didn't function, or then I did something wrong.

If someone has another solution, even if it isn't exactly what I'm asking for, then I'm also grateful as my current solution doesn't look too good.

Comment: There is a crucial information lacking for an adequate answer: what is `theExports`? Is it an array of numbers? Strings? If numbers, is the variable discrete or continuous?

Comment: Sorry for that. Some lack in my programming skills.
So it is an Array with strings ["Element1", "Element2", "Element3".. ]

Comment: No worries. I was about to answer, but the choice of the correct scale depends on that information.

Comment: Hopefully that helps in clarifying it. If it doesn't then I'll make a JSfiddle example of it this weekend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your data is an array of **strings** (clearly an categorical variable), the best option is using an ordinal scale, as you're doing right now.

However, it is possible to use a linear scale with a data like yours. For it to work, you'll pass the **index** of each element, not the element itself, to the scale (so, you have to mind the order of the elements in the array).

Something like this:

```
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, theExports.length - 1])
    .range(["yellow", "green"]);
```

Here is a demo, the data is this array:

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]
```

Based on the indices of the elements, we get a different colour:

```js
var data = "abcdefghij".split("");

var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, data.length - 1])
  .range(["yellow", "green"]);

var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", function(d) {
    return scale(data.indexOf(d))
  })
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Increasing the array...

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s"]
```

... won't break the scale:

```js
var data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrs".split("");

var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, data.length - 1])
  .range(["yellow", "green"]);

var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", function(d) {
    return scale(data.indexOf(d))
  })
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Finally, you can set midpoints:

```
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, (data.length - 1)/2, data.length - 1])
    .range(["yellow", "blue", "green"]);
```

```js
var data = "abcdefghijklmnopqrs".split("");

var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, (data.length - 1)/2, data.length - 1])
  .range(["yellow", "blue", "green"]);

var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", function(d) {
    return scale(data.indexOf(d))
  })
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks! A much better answer than I expected :)